# Not able to redirect page in CAKE PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

When i follow `$this->Auth->allow('login');` this approach, we are not able to redirect to dashboard page. If i follow `$this->Auth->allow();` this approach we are able to redirect to dashboard page.

But i need to use first approach for login.

I have a AppController.php which is performed Login Action.

Below is the AppController.php Code

```
function beforeFilter() {

    Security::setHash('md5');

    // Authenticate
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    $subdomain = substr( env("HTTP_HOST"), 0, strpos(env("HTTP_HOST"), ".") );


    if($this->params['controller']=="moderator")
    {

        //$this->Auth->allow(); // if i use this one my code is working fine.
        $this->Auth->allow('login');            

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'moderator', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'moderator', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'No username and password was found with that combination.';
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'moderator', 'action' => 'login');
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Admin';
    }

}
```

when we are login the page it will goto ModeratorController.php controller page and then check the usename and password using **Auth** , if username & password correct it will **call** the **dashboard** function.

Below is the ModeratorController.php Code

```
class ModeratorController extends AppController {

public $components = array('RequestHandler','Session',
        'Auth'=>array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields'=>array(
                                        'username'=>'username',
                                        'password'=>'password'
                                ),
                                'userModel'=> 'Admin'
                        ),
                ),
                'loginAction' =>array(
                        'Controller' => 'moderator',
                        'action' => 'login'
                ),
                'loginRedirect'=>array('Controller'=>'moderator', 'action'=>'index'),
                'logoutRedirect'=>array('Controller'=>'moderator', 'action'=>'index'),
                'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
                'authorize'=>'Controller',
                'loginError'=> 'Login error',


        )
);
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'),'Html','Paginator');


    function beforeFilter() {
        //used version cake 2.3.0.

        parent::beforeFilter();

    }


    // for moderator login process

    public function login() {

        if($this->Session->read('Auth.Admin.admin_id'))
        {           
             $this->redirect('dashboard');
        }

        if($this->request->data)
        {

         $this->Admin->set($this->data);
         if($this->Admin->validates())
         {
            if($this->Auth->login()){


                //$this->redirect('/moderator/dashboard');  // result: redirect to moderator/login              
                //$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'moderator', 'action' => 'dashboard')); // result: redirect to moderator/login
                //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); // result: redirect to moderator/login
                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard')) // result: redirect to moderator/login
                //$this->redirect('dashboard12'); // result: redirect to moderator/dashboard12 and give me 404. That result is correct
                //$this->redirect('/dashboard'); // result: redirect to /dashboard and give me 404. That result is also correct
                $this->redirect('dashboard')) // result: redirect to moderator/login
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email or password, try again'));
            }
        }
     }


    }


    public function dashboard()
    {
        echo "I am in dashboard";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should follow CakePHP's standards, which would make your controller `Moderators` and not `Moderator`. Then you would have to add `s` to all the references you have to the `moderator` controller in your `AppController.php` file

Comment: `dashboard.php`? Is that a model, controller? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things that are technically wrong:

1. When building in CakePHP you should follow its standards

   You should have `moderators` as your controller and not `moderator`
2. You make reference to dashboard.php

   `Is that a controller? or are you referring to the method`

If you have a controller name `ModeratorsController.php` and a method there name `dashboard()`, then you can redirect like this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'moderators', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

or you could even redirect like this

```
$this->redirect('/moderators/dashboard');
```

If the `dashboard.php` file you make reference is actually the controller, which in this case should be `DashboardsControler.php`, then you have to redirect to

```
$this->redirect('controller' => 'dashboards');
```

or

```
$this->redirect('/dashboards');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect('dashboard');
```

Should be

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
```

if this action is also in the dashboards controller.

Never use strings for links and redirects to internal pages of your app, only external links should use the string notation.

Also, is there any specific reason why you're not using the CookieComponent? Your cookie content won't be encrypted at all and you set a ton of cookies. Use the component.

Comment: Thanks for response
I tried $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard')); this one but there is no luck.

Comment: return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); in place of $this->redirect('dashboard');

Comment: also mentioned the $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false; in your controller like     function beforeFilter() {
        ...
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    }

Comment: Thanks @user2509485, I did the changes as you suggest above, but it didn't work, my bad luck :(

Comment: base on what BURZUM pointed out, you should redirect as `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'moderator', 'action' => 'dashboard'));

Comment: And I am assuming you have a `dashboard` method in your `Moderators` controller.

Comment: @AKKA-Web: Thanks.Yes i have dashboard method in ModeratorController. I have updated my code with your suggest changes and their result. Not luck yet.

Comment: Yeah... if you used `$this->redirect('/moderator/dashboard');` and nothing happened, then your problem might be somewhere else.... you might have to check your server logs or even CakePHP Log.